# 4 values ​were expected, but found 33. (near "(" at position 300)

Tags: mysql

4 values ​​were expected, but found 33. (near "(" at position 300)
SQL query:

```
-- Transfer the data in the table `city`
INSERT INTO `city` (`id`, `name`, `slug`, `country_id`) 
VALUES (1, 'Alor Gajah', 'alor-gajah ', 1), 
(2, 'Ampang Jaya', 'ampang-jaya', 1), 
(3, 'Alor Gajah', 'alor-gajah', 1),
(4, 'Alor Setar', 'alor- Setar', 1),
(5, 'Ampang', 'ampang', 1),
(6, 'Ampang Jaya', 'ampang-jaya', 1),
(7, 'Ayer Itam', 'ayer-itam' , 1,
(8, 'Ayer Keroh', 'ayer-keroh', 1),
(9, 'Ayer Molek', 'ayer-molek', 1),
(10, 'Ayer Tawar', 'ayer-tawar' , 1),
(11, 'Bagan Serai', 'bagan-serai', 1),
(12, 'Bahau', 'bahau', 1), (13, 'Balakong', 'balakong', 1),
(14, 'Bandar Baru Bangi', 'bandar-baru-bangi', 1), 
(15, 'Bandar Baru Salak Tinggi','bandar-baru-salak-tinggi', 1),
(16, 'Bandar Jengka Pusat', 'bandar-jengka-pusat', 1),
(17, 'Bandar Maharani', 'bandar-maharani', 1),
(18, 'Bandar Penggaram', 'bandar-penggaram', 1), 
(19, 'Banting', 'banting', 1),
(20, 'Batang Berjuntai', 'batang-berjuntai', 1), 
(21, 'Batu Arang', 'batu-arang', 1),
(22, 'Batu Berendam', 'batu-berendam', 1),
(23, 'Batu Caves', 'batu-caves', 1),
(24, 'Batu Delapan Bazaar', 'batu-delapan-bazaar', 1), 
(25, 'Batu Gajah', 'batu-gajah', 1), 
(26, 'Batu Sembilan Cheras', 'batu-sembilan- Cheras', 1),
(27, 'Bayan Lepas', 'bayan-lepas', 1), 
(28, 'Beaufort', 'beaufort', 1), 
(29, 'Bedong', 'bedong',1), 
(30, 'Bemban', 'bemban', 1), 
(31, 'Bentong', 'bentong', 1), 
(32, 'Beranang', 'beranang', 1), 
(33, 'Bidor ', 'bidor', 1), 
(34, 'Bintulu', 'bintulu', 1), 
(35, 'Bukit Bakri', 'bukit-bakri', 1), 
(36, 'Bukit Baru', 'bukit -baru', 1)
```

MySQL returns:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 41

this mysql is export from my database...is city SQL
I just key in all the city by manual...anybody can help me fix this?

Comment: Hi. It's not quite clear what you want. Please be more precise. Also: Here's the guide to know how to ask a good question on SO which will get an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please format your question so we can read it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

> ```
>  (6, 'Ampang Jaya', 'ampang-jaya', 1),
>    (7, 'Ayer Itam', 'ayer-itam' , 1,  
>    (8, 'Ayer Keroh', 'ayer-keroh', 1),
> ```

You have missed out the closing `)` on the row 7. Is this a typo?

## FIXED:

```
(6, 'Ampang Jaya', 'ampang-jaya', 1),
(7, 'Ayer Itam', 'ayer-itam' , 1),  
(8, 'Ayer Keroh', 'ayer-keroh', 1),
```